# Cocoa - constraints with subviews

Tags: cocoa, nslayoutconstraint

I have two NSButton's (`button1` and `button2`) they are added as subviews to a NSView (`buttonView1`,`buttonView2`). `buttonView1` and `buttonView2` are added to larger NSView (`menuBarView`).

So the setup looks like:

[image]

I've tried to do this by:

Adding constraints between `button1` and it's `buttonView1`. But the problem arise when I try to add `buttonView1` & `buttonView2` to `menuBarView`.

How would one code the constraints to accomplish this, with a visual format?

Comment: Clarify the final result you want so I may help.

Comment: I would like it to look exactly as in the picture.

Comment: Auto Layout is about dynamic layout. What looks "exactly as in the picture" may be not what you want when the bounds change. Any you didn't mention any metrics of or relationships between the views, a picture like this can not convey these informations.

Comment: Understood. I've already created the menuBarView. That view stretches to the same width as the window. The two buttons should have a margin from the two sides (LR) of the menuBarView with 10px. And be centered from top/bottom of the menuBarView. That's my plan anyway :)